# Multi Role Authentication

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am trying to develop a yesod application with two different types of logins: admins and users. I set up two models in config/model and the corresponding tables are generated automatically in the database by the scaffolding tool. However, I have no clue how to do the authentication: I can do either

```
    instance YesodAuth App where
       type AuthId App = AdminId
```

to authenticate admins or

```
   instance YesodAuth App where
       type AuthId App = UserId
```

to authenticate users. But how do I do both at the same time? TIA.

Comment: I think typically `admin` is just a boolean attribute on a `users` table. Is there any reason you want separate tables for them?

Comment: I would love to have a 1-to-many relation b/t admins and users so the admins can manage users, such as their profiles and other info.

Comment: One solution I could think of is to have two separate yesod applications connecting to the same database, one authenticating against admins and the other against users. More work to do, but overall probably a better architecture performance wise and security wise.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a `Role` type and persist field (must be declared in a separate file from 
where it is used as a field because of Template Haskell).

```hs
import Database.Persist.TH

data Role 
  = User
  | Admin

derivePersistField "Role"
```

Here is the database table that will use the `Role` as a field.

```
User
    email String
    role Role
```

Define the `AuthId` as a `UserId`

```hs
instance YesodAuth App where
  type AuthId App = UserId
```

Now create a function that looks up a user and checks if it has an `Admin` role. 
You may need to fix some of the function calls and types as I have not compiled
this locally.

```hs
isAdmin role = 
  case role of
    User  -> False
    Admin -> True

requireAdmin = do
  mEntityUser <- maybeAuth
  case mEntityUser of
    Just entityUser -> 
      if isAdmin . entityVal $ entityUser
        then pure entityUser
        else handleAuthLack
    _ -> handleAuthLack
```

Unfortunately [Yesod.Auth.handleAuthLack](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/c90c50911c7ad0ae0484d895c8c3a454117e4b4a/yesod-auth/Yesod/Auth.hs#L593) is not exported so you will need to redefine it locally.